# Something missing in PouchDB installation in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, pouchdb

> I have installed pouchDB in my Ionic 5 application and it also working find in browser and devices as well.

**But i'm getting following console error.**

PouchDB error: you must install a SQLite plugin in order for PouchDB to work on this platform.

- https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2
- https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage
- https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-websql

*Could anyone help to get it fixed.*

Answer (score 0):

here is a full example working with pouch DB
https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-sqlite-pouchdb/